# Is there difference of performance in Views with gradient background and without?

Tags: android, performance, view, gradient, shapes

I propose the question in terms of speed performance.
I assume it would be slower for android to build a shape which has a gradient than one that doest. Is that correct?
If so, is the difference significant or not? Even when using lists and many gradiented objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in speed should be barely noticeable if there is an advantage between the two,I've tested this multiple times before. I've used solid colors and gradients and both seemed to load at the same time. I don't think it is a significant load of work it has to handle,but processing the gradient may take longer than say a solid color.